# Special character reading in for loop issue in c

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, char

My situation is that I need to enter some characters and after reading a particular character (here *) I need to break out of the loop.

The code:

```
void main()
{
    int i=0,temp=0;
    char a[100];
    printf("Enter the array\n");

    for(i=0;a[i]!='*';i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&a[i]); 
    }
}
```

Even when I enter the '*' character it is not coming out of the loop.

I changed the code as shown below and it works correctly.

```
void main()
{
    int i=0,temp=0;
    char a[100];

    printf("Enter the array\n");

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
       scanf("%c",&a[i]);
       if(a[i]=='*')
           break;
    }
}
```

What is the issue with the first code? 
I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: @James Z : There is no issue with the code and also it is compiling well. But the problem comes at , when I am entering the '*' it is not coming out from the loop.

Comment: @Rabbid76-- the question you linked to is not a duplicate at all. While the handling of the newline is a potential problem in the posted code, this has nothing to do with the problem asked about in this question. The actual problem here has to do with attempting to use the value of an uninitialized variable (leading to UB), caused by a logic error in the code. The second example handles the newline in the same way, and OP seems happy with the way it works. They may change their mind about this later (when they look in the array), but that is a different question (and that is your duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void main()
> {
>   int i=0,temp=0;
>   char a[100];
>   printf("Enter the array\n");
>
>   for(i=0;a[i]!='*';i++)
>   {
>     scanf("%c",&a[i]); 
>   }
> }
> ```

The test `a[i]!='*'` is not performed using the same value of `i` as it is used in this statement

```
  scanf("%c",&a[i]);
```

In between scanning and testing `i` is incremented.

The sequence is:

1. set `i` to `0`
2. leave the loop if `i` isn't smaller then `100` anymore
3. test `a[0]` against `*`
4. scan into `a[0]`
5. increment `i`
6. leave the loop if `i` isn't smaller then `100` anymore
7. test `a[1]` against `*`
8. scan into `a[1]`
9. increment `i`
10. leave the loop if `i` isn't smaller then `100` anymore
11. and so on ...

From the above you also learn, that the code tests `a`'s elements *before* they get any value assigned. Doing so provokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour, which is a bad thing, as from this moment on *anything* could happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the loop evaluates the conditional **before** the loop executes the inner statements.

So, it goes like this:

1. We have a counter
2. Conditional is checked
3. Loop statements executed
4. Counter incremented

So the loop has already checked for the "*" before you even entered it.

Comment: OK.. Now I have modified the code like this and it is working now  for(i=0;c!='*';i++)
 {
   scanf("%c",&a[i]);
   c=a[i];
 }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `for` statement runs the `i++` increment *before* evaluating the `a[i] != '*'` loop exit condition.  This is quite visible if you run your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), a memory debugger which tracks uninitialized memory:

```
Enter the array
==3590== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3590==    at 0x108606: main (t.c:10)
==3590== 
*
==3590== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3590==    at 0x10862C: main (t.c:10)
==3590==
```

(The first uninitialized memory access happens before any character is read because the loop exit condition is checked before the first loop execution, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So it means that we are not having any option to check the exit condition like that. Only the second code snippet will work fine. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot check an exit condition like this before you have read the first character.